# Making this "(" currency ")" on iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I've been trying to put a value(double) between parentheses on iReport.
I get a Object as double and tried to put parenthesis on it, but it won't let me do it. It says: "Cannot cast from String to Double"
I've made like this:

```
"(" + $F{someValue} + ")"
```

Any idea? I don't want to create a String object on Java, unless there's no way to do it on iReport and it's really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you leave the value as is and select the format to be something like `(###0)`.
You can do it in **Text field properties --> Pattern**.